# How to point one sub-domain to another sub-domain and they can be used interchangeably

Tags: domains, redirects, subdomain, multiple-domains

I'm trying to do this

secure.domain2.com  -loads content from- secure.domain1.com

So if somebody goes to secure.domain2.com it will load the content of secure.domain1.com

Note that I don't want a redirect, so if someone goes to secure.domain2.com in the address bar it will still say secure.domain2.com even though it's loading content from secure.domain1.com

I've read that it's possible with a CName or something like that, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: The best way to do it _is_ via `CNAME`. You just add a `CNAME` record that points one domain/subdomain to the other. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=cname

Comment: To add to what @Lèsemajesté told you, CNAME's are typically setup at your registrar GoDaddy for example if you registered your domain there. Hosting provider also can help you get them setup. CNAME record in your DNS is what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CName record will do this.  But its probably a good idea just to do a redirect or somesort of URL rewrite to enforce that only one domain is used.   Also since you are using the word Secure, make sure you understand that both sites:
Secure.server1.com and Secure.server2.com need their own SSL certs.